# "Please wait..." message is required while posting answer from android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

I think title is self explanatory but still the problem is the waiting message which must be there whenever an app is performing for long running operation.

Right now, whenever you click on <kbd>SUBMIT</kbd> button, it freezes the UI until answer gets posted successfully. Application should display "Please wait..." message because its posting answer on remote database/site so it takes time.

[image]

Comment: Just throw it on a background thread - or that's what I would do in iOS...

Comment: @Undo yes being Android dev I can say the programmer has executed task by using Threading mechanism exist in Android. but still it should show some alert to user while doing long running task.

Comment: @Undo throwing it on a background thread is not a great solution because user should be notifying with some progress indicator while doing long running task or posting something on web.

Comment: With GCD on iOS, I can throw a progress indicator in the UI, spin off a new thread, and remove the indicator as soon as the blocking operations are done. Quite convenient.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed before version 1.0.